# Cannot find a default KieSession

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am trying to create jar using KieModule. Please have a look at the code.

```
public static ReleaseId createKJarWithMultipleResources(String id, String[] resourceFiles) throws IOException {
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieModuleModel kproj = ks.newKieModuleModel();
        KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

        for (int i = 0; i < resourceFiles.length; i++) {

            kfs.write("src/main/resources/" + id.replaceAll("\\.", "/")
                    + "/" + i + ".drl", resourceFiles[i]);
        }

        KieBaseModel kBase1 = kproj.newKieBaseModel(id)
                .setEqualsBehavior(EqualityBehaviorOption.EQUALITY)
                .setEventProcessingMode(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);

        KieSessionModel ksession1 = kBase1
                .newKieSessionModel(id + ".KSession1")
                .setType(KieSessionModel.KieSessionType.STATEFUL)
                .setClockType(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"));
        kfs.writeKModuleXML(kproj.toXML());

        KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
        Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
            if( results.hasMessages( org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
                System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
                throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
            }
        KieModule kieModule = kieBuilder.getKieModule();
        return kieModule.getReleaseId();
    }
```

But when I try to use the jar using the following code :

```
KieContainer kieContainer =
kieServices.newKieContainer(createKJarWithMultipleResources("1", 
new String[] 
{new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path to drl file")))}
));
KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

I get following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find a default KieSession
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.findKieSessionModel(KieContainerImpl.java:628)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:621)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:604)
    at com.sample.DroolsTest.test2(DroolsTest.java:87)
```

Am I missing anything? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved. I just had to change following lines in the code :

```
KieSessionModel ksession1 = kBase1
                .newKieSessionModel(id + ".KSession1")
                .setType(KieSessionModel.KieSessionType.STATEFUL)
                .setClockType(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"))
                .setDefault(true);
```

Notice the `setDefault(true)`, this was not there in original code.

Answer (score 3):

I've created kmodule.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF/ folder, with such conetnet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule"/>
```

and it worked for me

Without this file, it failed

Comment: That file is even mentioned at https://docs.drools.org/8.44.0.Final/drools-docs/drools/rule-engine/index.html#kie-sessions-con_rule-engine. Be aware it requires drools-xml-support.